# Debezium Kafka Connect for Postgresql receiving unexpected update message received

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, debezium-connect

I am using debezium kafka connect to stream postgresql database CDC events to kafka cluster. Currently, I am on version 1.9.0 but want to upgrade to version 2.4.0

We are using Kafka outbox pattern to stream database records to Kafka queues.

I am able to upgrade to 2.4.0 but getting a strange warning

```
 Unexpected update message received Struct{id=1} and ignored   [io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouterDelegate]
```

Below is my configuration

```
{
    "value.converter.delegate.converter.type.schemas.enable": "false",
    "database.password": "*****",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "publication.name": "dbz_outbox_pub",
    "slot.name": "debezium2",
    "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",
    "heartbeat.topic.prefix": "__debezium-heartbeat",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "transforms": "outbox",
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": "1",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "60000",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "transforms.outbox.table.field.event.key": "aggregateid",
    "publication.autocreate.mode": "filtered",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "1",
    "heartbeat.action.query": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS debezium_heartbeat (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);\nINSERT INTO debezium_heartbeat (id, ts) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET ts=EXCLUDED.ts;",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "transforms.outbox.type": "io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter",
    "table.include.list": "public.kafkaoutbox,public.debezium_heartbeat",
    "topic.creation.default.compression.type": "uncompressed",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "database.dbname": "superipdev_cellb",
    "value.converter.delegate.converter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "transforms.outbox.table.field.event.payload": "payload",
    "transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement": "${routedByValue}",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
    "key.converter.delegate.converter.type.schemas.enable": "false",
    "event.processing.failure.handling.mode": "warn",
    "schema.include.list": "",
    "snapshot.mode": "never",
    "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",
    "topic.prefix": "cell_b",
    "database.server.name": "cell_b",
    "name": "debezium2"
}
```

has anyone come across this before? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are doing an update on the outbox table. The SMT `EventRouterDelegate` on Debezium will ignore all operations except `INSERT` as you are not supposed to update the records from the outbox table.
Code for this is [here](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/e57c607bcf65f566045881e40a8cfc705c3c6e6d/debezium-core/src/main/java/io/debezium/transforms/outbox/EventRouterDelegate.java#L116)

Comment: I am not doing any updates on the outbox itself. It looks like heartbeat messages are sent to event router. Hearbeat table is getting updated frequently.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed, all records are going to pass through that SMT.